# OAuth - Invalid token: Request token used when not allowed

Tags: java, oauth, google-docs-api

I'm trying to access Google's Documents List API 3.0 with OAuth 2.0 but I'm having some troubles with a 401 Error.

After user have accepted, my code is the following:

```
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CLIENT_ID);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(token);
oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(tokenSecret);
oauthParameters.setScope("https://docs.google.com/feeds/");

service = new DocsService("myapp");
service.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

DocumentListFeed feed = service.getFeed(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/?v=3"), DocumentListFeed.class);
```

Then, in the last line -getFeed()- throws the exception:

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Token invalid - Invalid token: Request token used when not allowed.
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid token: Request token used when not allowed.</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - Invalid token: Request token used when not allowed.</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What's going on? On a static main test class works like a charm, but when I run it on the server this line does not works anymore. Any idea?

---

**SOLVED**

The access token needs to be retrieved this way, with a GoogleOAuthHelper, not with the GoogleOAuthParameters directly:

```
String accessToken = oauthHelper.getAccessToken(oauthParameters);
```

Comment: Could you put your solution in an answer and accept that answer?
This way the question is marked as solved and if anyone gets on this post (for any reason) the answer will be easy to be found.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not using OAuth 2.0 but OAuth 1.0 with HMAC-SHA1 as the signature method. To use OAuth 2.0, you need at least version 1.47.0 of the [gdata-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/) library and version 1.8.0-beta of the [google-oauth-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/) library.

Using the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) library provides helper classes to deal with Google's OAuth 2.0 implementation.

To retrieve OAuth 2.0 credentials, you can use this code snippet:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {

  // Retrieve the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET from an APIs Console project:
  //     https://code.google.com/apis/console
  static String CLIENT_ID = "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>";
  static String CLIENT_SECRET = "<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>";
  // Change the REDIRECT_URI value to your registered redirect URI for web
  // applications.
  static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
  // Add other requested scopes.
  static List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://docs.google.com/feeds");

  /**
   * Retrieve OAuth 2.0 credentials.
   * 
   * @return OAuth 2.0 Credential instance.
   */
  static Credential getCredentials() throws IOException {
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    // Step 1: Authorize -->
    String authorizationUrl =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, SCOPES).build();

    // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
    System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

    // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
    String code = in.readLine();
    // End of Step 1 <--

    // Step 2: Exchange -->
    GoogleTokenResponse response =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
            code, REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    // End of Step 2 <--

    // Build a new GoogleCredential instance and return it.
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build()
        .setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken()).setRefreshToken(response.getRefreshToken());
  }

  // …
}
```

Once you have the OAuth 2.0 credential, you can authorize a service object as follow:

```
// ...
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
// ...
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
// ...

public class MyClass {
  // …

  /**
   * Print document entries using the provided authorized DocsService.
   * 
   * @param credential OAuth 2.0 credential to use to authorize the requests.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws ServiceException
   */
  static void printDocuments(Credential credential) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    // Instantiate and authorize a new DocsService object.
    DocsService service = new DocsService("<YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME>");
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    // Send a request to the Documents List API to retrieve document entries.
    URL feedUri = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
    DocumentListFeed feed = service.getFeed(feedUri, DocumentListFeed.class);

    for (DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
      System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

The `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET` can be retrieved from the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and the `REDIRECT_URI` must match one that has been registered with your API Project.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. Fixed already to run with OAuth2. But your code has an error, this sentence is backwards: .setRefreshToken(response.getAccessToken()).setAccessToken(response.getRefreshToken());

Comment: can you provide the link for maven dependency for this jar  google-api-java-client ?

Comment: [There](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Maven) you go!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to add OAuth2.0 token to GData Service:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

service.setOAuth2Credentials(new Credential(BearerToken
    .authorizationHeaderAccessMethod())
    .setFromTokenResponse(new TokenResponse().setAccessToken(mToken)));
```

Make sure to import all the necessary libraries (which is a lot).

On Android token should be obtained using Google Play Services OAuth mechanism:

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(String email, String scopes);
```

Comment: This answer complements perfectly the most voted one...@zavidovych have you considered editing the other answer to enrich it?