# OAuth2 + GData Client API - usage

Tags: oauth-2.0, gdata-api, picasa

I am trying build a page, where a user can login using his google id and can access Picasaweb albums.

I am using gdata-java-client-1.47.1.zip (downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-src.java-1.47.1.zip)), google-oauth-java-client-1.10.1-beta.zip (downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-oauth-java-client-1.10.1-beta.zip&can=2&q=)) and google-api-java-client-1.10.3-beta.zip (downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-java-client-1.10.3-beta.zip&can=2&q=))

After setting up the OAuth2 workflow and getting the access token, I had created Credential object

```
return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
          .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build().setAccessToken(gtresponse.getAccessToken()).setRefreshToken(gtresponse.getRefreshToken());
```

When I am trying to create the PicasawebService object and set OAuth2Credentials as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249530/829542), I do NOT see a method setOAuth2Credentials in the list of methods available for PicasawebService object. I can only see setOAuthCredentials(parameters, signer) method available. Is this expected?

Not sure where I should go from here on how to access the web albums data? Kind of stuck! please help?

Thank you,

Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `PicasaClient` as is done in [this sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/picasa-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/picasa/cmdline/PicasaSample.java?repo=samples):

```
PicasaClient client = new PicasaClient(HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(credential));
```

You probably have to include [`PicasaClient`, `PicasaUrl` and the `model` classes](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2Fshared%2Fgdata%2Fshared-sample-picasa%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fapi%2Fservices%2Fpicasa) manually.

Another option would be to go down the [already deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub), but supported until April 2015, [AuthSub way](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java).

Comment: Jan - you are awesome. thank you very much for the tip. I am trying to use PicasaClient... will get back after implementation. :-)